# How to write 'or' query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Look for this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM usre u, item i   
WHERE u.user_id = ... AND i.item_id = ....
```

I want to make like this query, but I divided my items to two tables!

That means I want to write (`OR`) -> like this query :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    usre u, drink d OR food f
WHERE
    u.user_id =**
    AND d.drink_id =**
    OR f.food_id =**
```

This query is true? Or I make two queries and how?

Comment: wrap it with "(" and ")"

Comment: how ? like that ?

Comment: $data="SELECT * FROM usre u , drink d OR food f WHERE (u.user_id=** and d.drink_id=**)  OR f.food_id=**" ;

Comment: how ? like that ? $data="SELECT * FROM usre u , drink d AND food f WHERE u.user_id=** and d.drink_id=**  AND f.food_id=**" ;

Comment: you are welcome.. check this.. maybe helpful for you https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly you want to have result in one table in which will be data from two tables (drinks and foods)?

If that is the point, the query should looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user u
INNER JOIN drink d ON u.user_id = d.user_id
INNER JOIN food f ON u.user_id = f.user_id;
```

The `d.user_id` and `f.user_id` are foreign keys.

If you still have problem describe tables or specify the question if you mean something else.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean  .. thank you very much ❤️

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't work. the 'OR' statement requires the left side to be a boolean and cast to False in order to evaluate the statement at the right. What you are looking for is 'union', which you can use to merge results from one table with the results of other table(s). Beware that the columns types you fetch from one table must match the other table column types too.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html.

Btw, I also think you architected your DB the wrong way. Why have drinks and food in different tables? Yes, they can have some unique traits, but for the sake of simplicity you can put pretty much everything in a single table like: price, ingredients, cost, etc.

Comment: Ammm, maybe .. but I can't change now  thank you 

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN drink d on d.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN food f on f.user_id = u.id
```

Here I assume that User table have primary key ID and Drink and Food table have a foreign key 'user_id'